# A domain on plesk server suspends automatically everyday

Tags: windows-xp, domain

I have a domain on my plesk server and it suspends automatically everyday.

Why?

Comment: That is too bad.  Perhaps you could try and find some more details?  Check logs and such.

Answer (score 1):

Check domain's limits and resource usage (bandwidth, disk space, etc) it may be suspended by Plesk if it's using more resources than it's allowed.